# Git pull certain files only

Tags: git

It looks like someone has messed up the upstream box without branching (well done them) but I now need to do a software release of just one folder from that upstream. Any ideas how I do a pull of just that one folder from the upstream to the downstream git server for release without taking all the garbage stuff with it?

Comment: Git doesn't really like that :-( Maybe a userfs-based thing or some third-party tool could help.

Comment: I guess a work round might be me creating a new branch on the clean server and switching to it, then doing a checkout of the folder from the master. Not ideal but hey...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359424/detach-subdirectory-into-separate-git-repository try this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you perform a `git fetch` (rather than a `pull`) you will have access to the upstream and can decide what/how to merge those changes.